# Unit test v/s Integration test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I have a function which just reads a file line by line and does some logic for the output.

```cs
internal List<string> GetDataToTranslate(string filePath)
{
    List<string> dataToTranslate = new List<string>();

    using (StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
    {
        string line, finalLine;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        bool multiLineComment = false;

        while ((line = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            line = line.Trim();
            if (line.StartsWith("'"))
            {
                if (!multiLineComment)
                {
                    multiLineComment = true;
                }
                sb.Append(line.Substring(1) + DELIMITER);
            }
            else
            {
                if (multiLineComment)
                {
                    finalLine = sb.ToString();
                    dataToTranslate.Add(finalLine.Substring(0, finalLine.Length - DELIMITER.Length));
                    sb = sb.Clear();
                }
                multiLineComment = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return dataToTranslate;
}
```

The whole crux of the function is to do reading line by line from a stream, so does it even make sense to write a unit test for it? Should I just write an Integration test with a test file? Personally, I feel that I should not be writing a unit test because the method is totally dependant on an external file. Please suggest a best practice for this scenario.

Comment: Unit-test doesn´t neccessarily mean it´s independent from external ressources. A unit in the meaning of a unit-test is just a component that can be tested. If this componentn requires a file, fine. An integration-test on the other side tests between different components (the units). See https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2016/04/27/what-exactly-is-a-unit-in-unit-testing/.

Comment: Isn't that integration testing? @HimBromBeere

Comment: How you define a "unit" is up to you. There´s no general rule here, making your question quite opinion-based.

Comment: What can be the best practice in this case? @HimBromBeere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Personally, I feel that I should not be writing a unit test because the method is totally dependant on an external file

That's no reason not to test that code. It's a reason to refactor that code.

Modify it so that it can read from a provided `TextReader` (from which `StreamReader` inherits):

```
internal List<string> GetDataToTranslate(string filePath)
{
    using (StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(...))
    {
        return GetDataToTranslate(fileReader);
    }
}

internal List<string> GetDataToTranslate(TextReader reader)
{
    List<string> dataToTranslate = new List<string>();

    // ... your code

    return dataToTranslate;    
}
```

And from your unit test, pass it one that operates on a prepared string containing test data:

```
using (var reader = new StringReader("some-test-string"))
{
    var result = classUnderTest.GetDataToTranslate(reader);
}
```

You could of course also provide a text file with your unit test, if that's more maintainable than strings in code.

Comment: Would it be right if I say: This refactoring has outsourced the creation of `StreamReader` to another method. Now we can unit test our logic and we can basically ignore writing any unit test of the function where the creation of `StreamReader` happens?

Comment: That's reasonable, yes. You'd probably still want to test the method that creates the StreamReader, but that's a different question altogether.

Comment: I agree with your answer but I really feel that the testing frameworks sometimes have unnecessary influence on our code design.